# Apache docker container - .htaccess rewrite rule 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, docker

I have a rewrite rule in my .htaccess like so: `RewriteRule ^ /var/www/index.html [L]` (for an angular app's view routing)

However, when I go to /anything I get 404. Any idea why this would be?  Base docker container is [eboraas/apache](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/eboraas/apache/).

My dockerfile:

```
FROM eboraas/apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ADD . /var/www

EXPOSE 80
```

Edit: also tried rule `^.*$` with no luck. it appears to be that .htaccess is not being used/is being ignored, not that the rule is wrongly configured.

Comment: Is your .htaccess in your working directory (you reference it in ```ADD . /var/www```)?

Comment: yep. to be specific, index.html and .htaccess are both in /var/www along with the other site assets

Comment: Woudl a rule like `^.*$` would work better?

Comment: unfortunately still the same issue

Comment: probably best to dip into your container using ```docker exec -it --rm name-of-your-container /bin/bash``` and check that ```.htaccess``` has been copied and also rewrite has been moved to ```mods-enabled```

Comment: good hint! copied the .load file from mods-available to mods-enabled. now `phpinfo.php` is showing me that mod_rewrite is being loaded, but i'm still getting the 404...so close...

Comment: aha! figured it out. sites-enabled had `AllowOverride None`. just have to figure out how to make `AllowOverride All` the default and we're good. thanks for the help!

Comment: also your path is wrong, needed to be ```ADD . /var/www/html``` you dropped your index, .htaccess into /var/www

Answer (score 4):

In my case `AllowOverride All` was already in place for the whole `/var/www` directory, I just only had to add this into `Dockerfile`:

```
# enabling mod_rewrite
RUN cp /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

Comment: A better way to enable the rewrite module is to add RUN a2enmod rewrite to your Dockerfile